# Plot live data from a function that generates data

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib

I am a total beginner on programming, and its my first time here. I am trying to write a script for FEA analisys that reads data from a huge .msg file that gets updated by a third software during a simulation, and then plots a graph that updates itself everytime the .msg file gets updated by the third software.

With the tools Im familiar, my strategy was:

- to build a function that reads the data actively (with while loop)
  until the analysis finishes, and takes the values of interest from
  the text data, and copies it to another file (data.txt) that will receive the filtered data.
- build another function, that reads the filtered data (data.txt) to generate the plot.
- Use threading to run both functions syncronously

With his code I wrote i got the error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaxnw.png)

The data collecting seems to be working pretty fine, looks like the problem is when i call the thread that activates the plot function, as it needs somehow a position argument (i) that i dont really know how to define.

My code:

```
import os
from itertools import count
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style
import time
import threading

time1 = os.path.getmtime('SM_1Gz_PT_1.msg')

def getdata():

    index = count()
    final=0
    time1=''
    residual_force_list=[]  #lista com as linhas que contem a frase da largest residual force
    residual_forces=[]   #lista com o valor das residual forces
    iteration=[]
    while final == 0:

        if (time1 != os.path.getmtime('SM_1Gz_PT_1.msg')): #acessa o horário da ultima alteraçao no msg

            with open('SM_1Gz_PT_1.msg', 'rt') as lines:

                for line in lines: #Checa se a análise foi ou nao completada e adiciona ultima
                                   #linha de largest residual force à lista residual_force_list

                    if line[0:42].strip()=="THE ANALYSIS HAS BEEN COMPLETED":
                        final=1
                        # print(final)

                    if line[0:23].strip() == "LARGEST RESIDUAL FORCE": #add linha com ultima residual force a lista
                        residual_force_list.append(line)

                residual_forces.append(float(residual_force_list[-1][36:47]))
                force = residual_forces[-1]
                data=open('data.txt','a')
                data.write(f'{force},')
                data.write(f'{next(index)+1} \n')
                data.close()

                print(residual_forces)
                print(iteration, residual_forces)
                print(final)


            time1 = os.path.getmtime('SM_1Gz_PT_1.msg') #atualiza o horário da ultima modificação no msg

        time.sleep(1) #reduz a frequência na qual o loop checa por atualizaçoes no msg

style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = open('data.txt','r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('\n')
    xs = []
    ys = []
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            y, x = line.split(',')
            xs.append(int(x))
            ys.append(float(y))
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=getdata)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=animate)

t1.start()
t2.start()

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```